# Cisco ASA 8.0.4 reset ALL hitcnt

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I am trying to reset the hitcnt stats on all the access-list on all interfaces on my ASA5550.

I know about the `clear <access-list> counters` command.

But isn't there a way to clear the counters on ALL access-lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to manually go through and clear every access list. If you want a short list of which ACLs are applied to interfaces do a `show run access-group`. Or reboot your ASA.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty stupid from Cisco...obviously a reboot of the ASA is out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tcl script to reset hitcnt on all access-list.

```
#tclsh

set al [ exec "show access-list\" ]
set my_al [regexp -all -nocase -line -inline {#TODO} $al]

foreach nb $my_al {
       exec "clear $nb counters"
}
```

Edit : Start a small example in tcl but I have no router on hand, so it is not complete.